# Yii2 grid updating with editable field

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I followed the post on setting up an editable field in a grid here http://webtips.krajee.com/setup-editable-column-grid-view-manipulate-records/

Everything seems to work - I click on the field, change it's value and it shows the updated value in the grid. However - next time I refresh, the value reverts to the original value.

I've done a little debugging, and it would appear that the save in the controller is failing.

My table has a two key fields (key1 and key2) and a value field. I am trying to update this value field.

My view code is as follows:

```
$gridColumns = [
    'AnotherField',
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute'=>'value',
        'label' => 'some value',
        'editableOptions'=> [
            'header' => 'profile',
            'format' => Editable::FORMAT_BUTTON,
    ]
];
...
...
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns
]) ?>
```

and the controller code is as follows:

```
<snip>
//default code from gii-generated controller
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
// orig post said to use this: $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());

// Validate if there is an editable input saved via AJAX
if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {
    $model = new MyTable;

    $post = [];
    $posted = current($_POST['MyTable']);
    $post['MyTable'] = $posted;

    // Load model like any single model validation
    if ($model->load($post)) {
        // When doing $result = $model->save(); I get a return value of false
        $model->save();

        $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$output, 'message'=>'']);
    } 
    // Return AJAX JSON encoded response and exit
    echo $out;
    return;
}
// Non-AJAX - render the grid by default

</snip>
```

How does the controller know which record to update as I am only passing in the 'value' field, not the keys?

Do I somehow need to add these key1 and key2 fields to the view within the editable widget in order to get these values passed to the controller (so that the load and save know which record to update) or is there some other way that the controller handles this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution with some experimentation. I had to unserialize the $editableKey value and extract my key field values from it. I then call 'findModel' to load in the record to be updated.

The updated controller code is as follows:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

// Validate if there is an editable input saved via AJAX
if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {

    $keys = unserialize(Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey'));
    $model = $this->findModel($keys['key1'], $keys['key2']);

    // Store a default JSON response as desired by editable
    $out = Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'message'=>'']);
    // Fetch the first entry in posted data (there should only be one
    // entry anyway in this array for an editable submission)

    $values = current($_POST['MyTable']);

    // Load model like any single model validation
    if ($model->key1) {
        // Update the Profile with the new value passed in   
        $model->value = $values['value'];
        $model->save();
    ...
```

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

In the example on this page http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo (you can see the column definition too) you can see with firebug that the following values are sent:

```
Book[5][buy_amount] 1
_csrf   MEQ0NnEzNjFhd2dBB2wBCHN0cGVCA3lfZHF1TDReRlAAcQNUPUFjBQ==
editableIndex   5
editableKey 6
hasEditable 1
```

I believe the 5 in Book[5] is probably matching the index of the record.

This part does that from what I see

```
$post = [];
$posted = current($_POST['Book']);
$post['Book'] = $posted;
```

I have never used the widget so I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I believe somehow the editablekey maps the key to the record. Looking with firebug at the demos.krajee.com example and comparing to my own code, I see they have editableKey = 1 whereas my code has editableKey = "a:2:{s:7:"key1";i:1;s:10:"key2";i:2;}" - am not sure how yii2 handles this - will do some further digging.

Comment: are you sure that it is not what I said? By looking at the code that they have in the controller, I do not see editableKey or editableIndex anywhere in there. First I thought like you that they might use those fields, but I do not see where they would.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a solution of updating table using Editable column. Looking at the ajax post I got similar like this output:

```
Book[5][buy_amount] 1
_csrf   MEQ0NnEzNjFhd2dBB2wBCHN0cGVCA3lfZHF1TDReRlAAcQNUPUFjBQ==
editableIndex   5
editableKey 6
hasEditable 1
```

Here I found the value of editableKey is the value of id of the table.
So to update specific row on gridview column I used the editableKey and update based on it.
In controller :

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {
$_id=$_POST['editableKey'];
$model = $this->findModel($_id);

$post = [];
$posted = current($_POST['MyTable']);
$post['MyTable'] = $posted;

// Load model like any single model validation
if ($model->load($post)) {
    // When doing $result = $model->save(); I get a return value of false
    $model->save();
    if (isset($posted['buy_amount'])) 
    {
      $output =  $model->buy_amount;
    }
    $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$output, 'message'=>'']);
} 
// Return AJAX JSON encoded response and exit
echo $out;
return;
}
```

I just get the post data using `$_id=$_POST['editableKey'];`
and set my `$model` as `$model = $this->findModel($_id);`
now you can update multiple editable column just adding condition like this

```
if (isset($posted['buy_amount'])) 
{
  $output =  $model->buy_amount;
}
```

Thanks!